# Mysql_query SQL command check

Tags: php, mysql

Good day guys.
Can you check this line of code if it is right i can't find any answer.

```
$comments_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY commentsID DESC WHERE postID=".$_GET['blog']);
```

And I know that this is old and unsafe way to reach mysql. But this is all that i can learn from old books.

Comment: please read it from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ or some other good tutorial sites..`where` needs to be put first then comes the `order by`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clauses of a SQL statement come in this order:

1. SELECT
2. FROM
3. JOIN (if any)
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY (if any)
6. ORDER BY
7. LIMIT

You have your WHERE after your ORDER BY.  You Can't Do That™.

Comment: So this is the right code? 
$comments_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postID=".$_GET['blog']." ORDER BY commentsID DESC");

Comment: It looks right to me. Does it work?

Comment: No It doesn't work. And Sublime text is not even coloring it right.

Comment: It's right but i had problem with something else... Thank you a lot

Comment: Be careful with IDE text color-coding in mixed-language environments (yours is sql/php). They often cause confusion.

Comment: I know. Now it is coloring right... Like before... Thanks again